# SMTP mail stuck in the mail queue under windows server 2012 R 2- IIS 8.5

Tags: email, iis, smtp

I try to send out mail by setup the windows server 2012 R2 with PHP / IIS, I check the smtp log, for some reason mail stuck in the inetpub/mailroot/queue folder.

I had setup two windows server in two different location, SMTP part is setup exactly the same, but one works and one doesn't.

I enabled and check the SMTP log file on both machine and I found out the one it works, the log file include the "OutboundConnectionResponse" entries. The one that is not working is missing the "OutboundConnectionResponse".

I also tried to telnet into the port 25 and it works fine, so the port is not blocked on the local host. Is that possible something blocked at the router level? the windows firewall is off on that box.

Any idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check your ISP if port 25 is not blocked on their side